# GitHub - Remove pushed commits without affecting local repository

Tags: git, github

What is the best way to remove commits from GitHub without affecting my local repositories since i made some commits that i wish to keep?

Github repository has two wrong commits that i desire to remove while keeping the commits on my local repository.

Comment: Work on a separate branch.

Comment: create a new branch for the commits that you want to keep (in your local repository) with 'git branch -b KeepThisBranch  SHAofCommitToKeep '.  Then remove the commits from the old branch inside GitHub as normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the current repository state is this:

```
server:         A---B---C---D
                            ^master

workstation:    A---B---C---D
                            ^HEAD
                            ^master
                            ^origin/master
```

And the desired state is this:

```
server:         A---B
                    ^master

workstation:    A---B---C---D
                            ^HEAD
                            ^master
                    ^origin/master
```

Then what you can do to get there is this:

```
$ git push --force origin bbbbbbbb:master
```

where `bbbbbbbb` is the commit hash of B.

Notes:

- As with all `--force`, be careful. You can get yourself into a place that's difficult to come out of.
- Make sure all your team members know what you're doing. They may inadvertently push C and D right back into the repository if they don't update their own repository correctly after you push.
- If any other tags/branches point to commits C and D, they'll remain accessible through there.
- Commits C and D and all changes in them may not be instantly deleted. They will be removed in a garbage collection pass at an undefined moment in time.

Comment: Beat me to it!  Also note that you can use shortcuts like `HEAD~2` to refer to the commit two back in history.